# t=turtle.Pen() says turtle doesn't have the attribute Pen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

After importing turtle, I keep trying to put `t=turtle.Pen()` but it says turtle doesn't have the attribute Pen.

I have tried

`turtle=turtle.Pen()`
`t=turtle.Turtle()`
`myturtle=turtle.Pen()`

`my turtle =turtle.Turtle()`

but every time it says turtle does not have attribute whatever I put as my attribute. Does anyone know why this is happening? I have python version 3.5.0

Comment: Did you name your source file turtle.py by any chance?

Comment: After importing `turtle`, what does `print(turtle)` display?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief turtle example:

https://gist.github.com/wolfospealain/af3410a9e71eb2ff7be5625174c4f4c5

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import turtle

turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.left(45)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(65)
turtle.circle(150,350)
turtle.home()
big=("Arial", 36, "normal")
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-40,150)
turtle.write("Hello World!", font=big)
turtle.home()
turtle.back(20)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Notice how you must first `import turtle` to make the turtle library available to your program.

Notice, too, that all the method names are lower case (for example, `turtle.penup()`).

I think you probably meant [turtle.penup()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.penup), which allows you to "move" without drawing.

You can find complete turtle documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html

Here is a short tutorial you might find helpful: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/turtle-programming-in-python

Comment: There is a `turtle.Pen()`, it's a valid synonym for `turtle.Turtle()`.  I think the problem is more likely the OP named their source file turtle.py.